# How to change Flat UI checkbox background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am trying to figure out the css class to overwrite the default checkbox style in Flat UI, but even after i spend 4 hours, i cannot able to figure out the css class which is responsible for the checkbox design.

I want to overwrite the default green background to white and green tick mark to black , in which class i have to do this?. Please help me.

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox, right click the checkbox and click 'Inspect Element' - that will show you all the CSS effecting that checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Elendil, i have tried that too, but it is liked with many class'es i cannot able to find out the exact class.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old post, but I was looking for this my self, and I found the answer.*

Because the checkboxes actually characters from a font" you can change the color of the fonts using the color property like so

```
.checkbox input.custom-checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked + .icons .icon-checked,
.radio input.custom-checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked + .icons .icon-checked,
.checkbox input.custom-radio[type="radio"]:checked + .icons .icon-checked,
.radio input.custom-radio[type="radio"]:checked + .icons .icon-checked {
  color:#BAFF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
.radio, 
.checkbox 
{
    background: green !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey just use the same class to over right the design. but your css must be below the falt ui and bootstrap css.